# How to prevent duplicate

Tags: impala

There are two tables.

PURCHASES

| customer_id | purchase_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-02-2023 |
| 1 | 01-02-2023 |
| 1 | 15-05-2023 |
| 2 | ... |

CONTACTS

| customer_id | contact_dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 06-01-2023 |
| 1 | 15-01-2023 |
| 1 | 20-03-2023 |
| 2 | ... |

For each customer we need to calculate the number of those purchases that were made within 30 days after contact with the customer.

```
SELECT
    p.customer_id,
    count(p.contact_dt) as purchases_count
FROM purchases as p
INNER JOIN contacts as c
    ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id 
    AND p.purchase_dt between contact_dt and date_add(contact_dt, 30)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

The problem is that there is no purchase ID in the table.
Thus, the purchase from 01-02-2023 will be counted 4 times instead of 2.

The question is how to prevent it.

Comment: have u tried to count (DISTINCT p.contact_dt)?

Comment: It will count 1 instead of 2 for 01-02-2023 purchase

Comment: Sure, my bad I didn't get the question with attention... I've posted my query below

Answer (score 0):

Use `select distinct` but in the `sub-query` inside join condition

```
SELECT
    p.customer_id,
    count(p.customer_id) as purchases_count
FROM (select distinct customer_id, purchase_dt from purchases) as p
INNER JOIN contacts as c
    ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id 
    AND p.purchase_dt between contact_dt and date_add(contact_dt, 30)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, to get the count of purchases made by each customer, within 30 days of contact, with MySQL (I've changed the date format for convenience).
In practice, the trick consists in using a subquery to selects distinct pairs of customer_id and purchase_dt values that meet the condition, and then count from the resulting joint.
Hope that it is what you wanted!

```sql
CREATE TABLE contacts (
   customer_id INTEGER,
   contact_dt VARCHAR(10)
);
CREATE TABLE purchases (
   customer_id INTEGER,
   purchase_dt VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO contacts (customer_id, contact_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-01-06');
INSERT INTO contacts (customer_id, contact_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-01-15');
INSERT INTO contacts (customer_id, contact_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-03-20');
INSERT INTO purchases (customer_id, purchase_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-02-01'); 
INSERT INTO purchases (customer_id, purchase_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-02-01'); 
INSERT INTO purchases (customer_id, purchase_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-01-10');
INSERT INTO purchases (customer_id, purchase_dt) VALUES (1, '2023-03-10');
    
    
SELECT p.customer_id, COUNT(*) as buyed
FROM purchases p
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT c.customer_id, p.purchase_dt
      FROM purchases p
      INNER JOIN contacts c
      ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
      WHERE p.purchase_dt BETWEEN c.contact_dt AND DATE_ADD(c.contact_dt, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    ) AS selection
ON p.customer_id = selection.customer_id AND p.purchase_dt = selection.purchase_dt
GROUP BY p.customer_id;
```

Output:
customer_id    buyed
1                                     3